# How to evaluate $\int_C{\frac{1}{z^2+1}}$ along the following contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

So the contour I'm given is "the square centered at the origin with side lengths 2 oriented positively".

We have

$$\int_C{\frac{1}{z^2+1}}$$

Now, since our "bad" areas are $i$ and $-i$, which the perimeter of the square goes through, I'm not sure how to account for those when applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Thanks for taking a gander!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2 + 1}\, dz = \int_C \frac{\frac{1}{2i}}{z - i}\, dz - \int_C \frac{\frac{1}{2i}}{z + i}\, dz.$$

Comment: Do you mean 
$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2 + 1}\, dz = \int_C \frac{1/2i}{z - i}\, dz - \int_C \frac{1/2i}{z + i}\, dz$? 

Still, it's the singularities of it that I'm confused about.

Comment: Both $i$ and $-i$ lie inside $C$.

Comment: So both are $2\pi i$?

Comment: No, they're both $2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2i} = \pi$.

Comment: Exactly eh! Thanks.